# Cannot Initialize Object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to initialize an object in Ruby, but I get an error: "undefined method `Thing' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

However, isn't that what the initialize method is for?

```
class Thing
  def initialize(id, color)
    @id = id
    @color = color
  end
end

Thing thing = Thing.new(1, "blue")
```

Comment: `Thing thing = Thing.new(1, "blue")` r u sure is it okay ? :)

Comment: `thing = Thing.new(1, "blue"); p thing` do this ))

Comment: While the answer explains the resolution the error is caused by the fact that that parser views your code as `Thing(thing= Thing.new(1, "blue"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are created by simply [assigning](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html) to them. You don't have to declare them or specify their type. (in fact, you can't)

Just write:

```
thing = Thing.new(1, "blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is dynamically typed, meaning that the type of a variable is determined based on the value assigned to it at runtime.
unlike C or Java or other languages variables in ruby do not require explicit type declarations

please check this

```
step = 10
=> 10
step.class
=> Integer
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, at least not in a way that's obvious to me. Can you add an explanation as to why this would fix the "undefined method" error that was cited? If you can't, you should consider deleting this response.